# Is there a way to save images with none stretching in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-9.3, imagery

I have some satellite images, when I imported these in ArcGIS and went to properties and then symbology tab, I saw stretch type was set to standard deviation. I want to save these images with no stretch as I import these images into ArcMap, to display the images without stretching , how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing what you want is:

You have to set each image to non stretched and then select all the images in the Table of Contents (TOC) on the left side of ArcMap (click the image at the top of the TOC -> press Shift on your keyboard-> click the image at the bottom of the TOC).

When you have selected all the images you make a right click on one of the selected images and choose "Group". Now you have a Group Layer in your TOC containing all your images.

You can select the Group Layer name and press F2 to rename it if you want, but now you simply have to right click the Group Layer end choose "Save as Layer...". The resulting Layer File you can add to ArcMap, and you should get all the images added with the non stretched symbology.

Hope this helps you. :-)

Comment: hi . thank you so much for your help but i want to save each image with none stretch .

Comment: In that case you just skip the part about the Group Layer - simply set each image to non stretched and right click each image in the TOC and choose "Save as Layer...". In the future you add each Layer-file to ArcMap instead of each image.